# Mysql select most recent with date desc for each artist

Tags: mysql, sql

i have 3 tables:

- PK: Primary Key
- FK: Foreign Key

**mp3s** table:

```
+---------+--------------+----------------------+
| id (PK) | tarck_title  | date                 |
+---------+--------------+----------------------+
| 100     | shakira      |  2001-01-12 00:00:00 | 
| 101     | metallica    |  2002-01-12 00:00:00 | 
| 102     | james blunt  |  2003-01-12 00:00:00 | 
| 103     | shakira      |  2004-01-12 00:00:00 | 
| 104     | anathema     |  2005-01-12 00:00:00 | 
| 105     | nelson       |  2006-01-12 00:00:00 | 
| 106     | shakira      |  2007-01-12 00:00:00 | 
| 107     | bb king      |  2008-01-12 00:00:00 | 
| 108     | metallica    |  2009-01-12 00:00:00 | 
| 109     | nelson       |  2010-01-12 00:00:00 | 
| 110     | shakira      |  2011-01-12 00:00:00 | 
| 111     | bb king      |  2012-01-12 00:00:00 | 
+---------+--------------+----------------------+
```

**artists** table:

```
+---------+----------------+
| id (PK) | artist_name    |
+---------+----------------+
| 14      | shakira        |
| 221     | metallica      |
| 320     | james blunt    |
| 328     | shakira        |
| 1004    | anathema       |
| 1140    | nelson         |
| 1401    | bb king        |
+---------+----------------+
```

and **tags** table: *PK(mp3_id, artist_id)*

```
+-------------+----------------+
| mp3_id (FK) | artist_id (FK) |
+-------------+----------------+
| 100         | 14             |
| 101         | 221            |
| 102         | 320            |
| 103         | 14             |
| 104         | 1004           |
| 105         | 1140           |
| 106         | 14             |
| 107         | 1401           |
| 108         | 221            |
| 109         | 1140           |
| 110         | 14             |
| 111         | 1401           |
+---------+--------------------+
```

now, i need good query for this resaults. i want select 3 latest track from **(shakira & bb king)** `order by date` track. like this:

```
+---------+--------------+----------------------+
| id (PK) | tarck_title  | date                 |
+---------+--------------+----------------------+
| 110     | shakira      |  2011-01-12 00:00:00 | 
| 106     | shakira      |  2007-01-12 00:00:00 | 
| 103     | shakira      |  2004-01-12 00:00:00 | 
| 111     | bb king      |  2012-01-12 00:00:00 | 
| 107     | bb king      |  2008-01-12 00:00:00 | 
+---------+--------------+----------------------+
```

or select 3 latest track from **(shakira & bb king & metallica)** `order by date` track. like this:

```
+---------+--------------+----------------------+
| id (PK) | tarck_title  | date                 |
+---------+--------------+----------------------+
| 110     | shakira      |  2011-01-12 00:00:00 | 
| 106     | shakira      |  2007-01-12 00:00:00 | 
| 103     | shakira      |  2004-01-12 00:00:00 | 
| 111     | bb king      |  2012-01-12 00:00:00 | 
| 107     | bb king      |  2008-01-12 00:00:00 | 
| 108     | metallica    |  2009-01-12 00:00:00 | 
| 101     | metallica    |  2002-01-12 00:00:00 | 
+---------+--------------+----------------------+
```

**EDIT:**

this query is working but sort date desc not working:

```
SELECT `id`, `tarck_title`, `date`
        FROM `mp3s`
        WHERE `id` IN (
            SELECT x.`mp3_id`
            FROM `tags` x
            INNER JOIN `tags` y ON y.`artist_id` = x.`artist_id` AND y.`mp3_id` <= x.`mp3_id`
            INNER JOIN `mp3s` z ON z.`id` = x.`mp3_id`
            WHERE x.`artist_id` IN (SELECT `artist_id` FROM `tags` WHERE `mp3_id` = 103)
            GROUP BY x.`mp3_id` HAVING COUNT(*) <= 3
            ORDER BY z.`date` DESC, x.`artist_id` DESC, x.`mp3_id`)
```

Comment: Ok... So aren't you able to select? What query did you try? What result did it return?

Comment: @ChetanRanpariya i test 2, 3 query try. but order by date is my problem

Answer (score 1):

If I found the question, the query would be like the following:

```
  (SELECT m.* FROM (tags as t JOIN artists as a on t.artist_id = a.id) JOIN mp3s as m on m.id = t.mp3_id
  WHERE a.artist_name = 'Shakira'
  ORDER BY m.date DESC
  LIMIT 3)
  UNION
  (SELECT m.* FROM (tags as t JOIN artists as a on t.artist_id = a.id) JOIN mp3s as m on m.id = t.mp3_id
  WHERE a.artist_name = 'bb King'
  ORDER BY m.date DESC
  LIMIT 3);
```

Also, If you want a compressed format of the query, you can find it in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2129693/using-limit-within-group-by-to-get-n-results-per-group).

Comment: your answer is true, but i want without `union`. because number of `a.artist_name` not fix.

Comment: @grizzly Did you see the referenced post?

Comment: yes.  [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2129693/using-limit-within-group-by-to-get-n-results-per-group) ???

Comment: @grizzly Ya. it's the exactly as same as your question.

Answer (score 1):

In MySQL, you can do this with variables:

```
SELECT m.*
FROM (SELECT m.*,
             (@rn := if(@a = a.id, @rn + 1,
                        if(@a := a.id, 1, 1)
                       )
             ) as rn
      FROM tags t JOIN
           artists a 
           ON t.artist_id = a.id JOIN
           mp3s m 
           ON m.id = t.mp3_id CROSS JOIN
           (SELECT @a := -1, @rn := 0) params
      WHERE . . .
      ORDER BY a.id, m.date DESC
     ) m
WHERE rn <= 3;
```

In the inner `WHERE`, you can specify whatever artists or other conditions that you like.

Comment: I've tested, but not sorted by date

Comment: @grizzly . . . I don't understand your comment.  You can sort the overall data however you want with an `order by` in the outermost query.  Your question seems to be about choosing the top three for each artist based on the most recent date.  Are you saying that doesn't work?

Comment: `m.date desc` doesn't work. Song selection was based on the old date

Comment: @grizzly . . . How are the dates stored, as dates?  It is hard to see how this would not return the three most recent dates for each artist.  Perhaps the wrong id was being used.  I notice the right column is `a.id` for the `order by` and the `if()`.